# Load data from one model and structure it like it came from another

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have static and dynamic products on our website. Static products are your basic products that are loaded from a database. Dynamic products are user generated on the fly (from applications like "*Design your own ring*").

When a purchase is made, for each product sold there is an entry into a table/model called *purchases*, the purchase model holds the *sale price*, *quantity*, etc. for the product that was sold. the purchase model **hasOne** product.

This works fine for static products. However dynamic products need to have their data saved somewhere. I don't want to save the dynamic product to the products table because I don't want them showing up anywhere else except for purchases. Plus they also can contain extra values that static products don't have.

However, when I load the dynamic product data, I want it to be structured like a regular product, so I wont have to write different logic for processing static vs dynamic products.

I came up with the idea of creating a model/table called **mavs** (Model Attribute Values) with a table structure like so:

```
id      purchase_id     model       attribute       value

1       3               Product     name            foo
2       3               Product     description     bar
3       3               Other       size            7
```

I would set purchase as **hasMany** mavs. The default way it would load this data though would look like this:

```
[Purchase] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ...
                    [Product] => Array
                        (
                        )
                    [Mav] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [purchase_id] => 78
                                    [model] => Product
                                    [attribute] => name
                                    [value] => foo
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [purchase_id] => 78
                                    [model] => Product
                                    [attribute] => description
                                    [value] => bar
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [purchase_id] => 78
                                    [model] => Other
                                    [attribute] => size
                                    [value] => 7
                                )

                        )
                )
        )
```

I want to structure it like this:

```
[Purchase] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ...
                    [Product] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => foo,
                            [description] => bar
                        )
                    [Other] => Array
                        (
                            [size] => 7
                        )
                )
        )
```

That way it will be able to be processed just like a regular product.

---

I thought I could achieve this by altering the data in the **afterFind** callback in the Mav model. I created this function:

```
public function afterFind( $results, $primary )
{
    debug($results);

    foreach($results as $key => $data)
    {
        $model      = $data['Mav']['model'];
        $attribute  = $data['Mav']['attribute'];
        $value      = $data['Mav']['value'];

        $results[$key] = array( $model => array( $attribute => $value ) );
    }

    debug($results);

    return $results;
}
```

I am debuging the data before and after the change it goes from this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Mav] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [purchase_id] => 78
                    [model] => Product
                    [attribute] => name
                    [value] => foo
                )

        )

)
```

To this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [name] => foo
                )

        )

)
```

which is exactly what I was intending. However the data I get from a `$purchase->find()` is still structured in the original way. I am not sure why it is not reflecting my changes made in the **afterFind** callback.

So how can I acheive this? Also if anyone can offer better solutions to my problem all together, those are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

you are using $results twice.

create a new array with the data structure you like and return the new array.

Comment: This has no effect, I was overriding the original `$results` with the new `$results`. I tried creating `$new_results` and returning that instead (*per your suggestion*) but there was no difference.

Comment: did you set `$primary`to true/false?

Comment: I did not do anything with `$primary` should I? If so, where?

Comment: Also note, if I just change the values in the `$results` array, it is working. Its only when I am actually changing the structure of the `$results` array that it fails. I think there might be a check somewhere in the core that ignores the results of `afterFind` if the array structure has been compromised. I can't seem to find where though.

Comment: I tried setting $primary to true and then to false. Neither had any effect. I think the problem is more to do with altering the array structure of `$results` to no longer resemble the Mav model.

Comment: tried to test it on localhost and couldn't find an answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your function to do what you *actually* seemed to intend. See it working over here: http://codepad.org/8ajWNai8

```
function afterFind( $results, $primary )
{
    foreach($results as &$currentResult)
    {
        foreach($currentResult["Mav"] as &$mavDetails)
        {
            $model     = $mavDetails['model'];
            $attribute = $mavDetails['attribute'];
            $value     = $mavDetails['value'];

            if (!array_key_exists($model, $currentResult)) 
            {
                $currentResult[$model] = array();
            }
            $currentResult[$model][$attribute] = $value;
        }
        unset($currentResult["Mav"]);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Since I have had *zero* exposure to CakePHP so far, this could be subtly wrong in the context. The function itself however seems to create exactly what you describe in your question.

Comment: Thanks, this does work in your example. The function itself does return what I want it to. However, I think something somewhere else in the framework is preventing it from working. The function is not something I call myself but a callback or *hook* that runs whenever I load data via a data model. It supposed to be so you can alter the data returned, in fact when I just change the array values but not the array structure it works. When I change the array though it does not work. I don't think there is anything wrong in the function but something somewhere in the framework core preventing this.

Comment: @John Isaacks: This is very strange indeed. I'm not sure why the function must return a value anyway, since it could perfectly work on the original array via a reference (my first version of the answer did this, until I read the relevant docs). You *could* easily try stating `afterFind( &$results, $primary )` and comment out the `return` statement to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I tried that and I got this error: `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php on line 893` I looked at the code on line 893 and its: `$data = $model->{$className}->afterFind(array(array($className => $results[$i][$className])), false);` is it because the array is anonymous?

Comment: @John: Yes, you can't pass by reference like this in PHP. You must store the array in a variable before.